# Redim Preserve a 2D Array from Excel Table

Tags: arrays, vba

Try as I might I cannot correct a "Subscript out of Range" error that the code below is throwing on the last line of code below when I try to expand the size of an array with Redim Preserve.  Any ideas as to what might be wrong?

```
Sub Demo()

'Set Excel variables
    Dim wb As Workbook:                 Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim wsCluster As Worksheet:         Set wsCluster = wb.Worksheets("Cluster")
    Dim initialK As ListObject:         Set initialK = wsCluster.ListObjects("k")

'Set Array variables
    Dim kArray() As Variant
        ReDim kArray(1 To initialK.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, 1 To initialK.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count)
            kArray = initialK.DataBodyRange

'Set Other variables
    Dim coordResults As Variant, kResults As Variant, addKs As Variant, dupeArray As Variant
    Dim transferLat As Double, transferLong As Double, potDupeCount As Long, expandK As Long, nextAvailK As Long

'Run the assignment function once, then loop through average/assign functions
    coordResults = Assign(coordArray, kArray)
        For i = 1 To 3
            kResults = Average(coordArray, kArray, coordResults)
            coordResults = Assign(coordArray, kArray)
        Next i

'Run the radius function
addKs = AdjustForRadius(coordArray, kResults, coordResults)

'Add the new, deduped centroid data to the kResults array
    expandK = UBound(addKs, 1) + UBound(kArray, 1)
    ReDim Preserve kArray(1 To expandK, 1 To 3)

End Sub
```

The functions are working properly.  The "expand" variable is good.

I have tested everything I know.

Jake

Comment: You cannot redim preserve any dimension but the last one.

Comment: You can only `ReDim` the last dimension of the array. You are trying to do it to the first dimension.

Comment: Sorry, I am not understanding.  I am trying to go from array(1 to 150, 1 to 3) to array(1 to 159, 1 to 3).  This is not possible?

Comment: NO. do it like from array(1 to 3, 1 to 150) to array(1 to 3, 1 to 159) and then in the end transpose. You cannot change rows in an array.

Comment: OK.  That makes sense.  Thanks to you all.